# How to have two submit options in an HTML form with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, firebase, submit

So, I have a form where I want to have two buttons, each of which will save the inputted data to a different location. I'm not sure if a form is the proper way to do this, as pressing the "enter" button is supposed to activate the submit function, which doesn't work when there are two different options for submit. Other solutions on here that I have come across seem to mostly be using PHP, but I am using Firbase for my backend, so my solution must be in Javascript. One button will save an inputted link to a bookmarks collection and the other will save it to a favorites collection.

Here is my attempt (which doesn't work):

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const btnName = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-type').name;
    console.log(btnName);
    if (btnName === 'save_bookmark') {
        let theCurrentUser = auth.currentUser;
        db.collection('users/'+ theCurrentUser.uid +'/bookmarks').add({
            website: form['website'].value,
            url: form['url'].value
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err.message);
        })
    } else if (btnName === 'save_favorite') {
        db.collection('favorites').add({
            website: form['website'].value,
            url: form['url'].value
        });
    }
    form.website.value = '';
    form.url.value = '';
})
```

And here is the corresponding HTML:

```
<div class='row logged-in show-none'>
    <form class='col s12' id='add-bookmark'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='input-field col s4'>
                <input type='text' name='website' placeholder='Enter name of bookmark'>
            </div>
            <div class='input-field col s4'>
                <input type='text' name='url' placeholder='Enter link to bookmark'>
            </div>
            <div class='input-field col s1'>
                <button class='btn waves-effect waves-light' name='save_bookmark' value='save'>Save</button>
            </div>
            <div class='input-field col s1'>
                <button class='btn waves-effect waves-light btn-type' name='save_favorite' value='favorite'>Favorite</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a checkbox called "add to favorites" right before the save button, and remove the add favorite button. That way you default to a normal save on enter if the user ignores the favorite checkbox.

```
<div class='input-field col s1'><input id="fav" type='checkbox' name='favorite' value='favorite'></div>
```

Then you could have:

```
    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const fav = document.getElementById('fav').checked;
        if (fav) {
                db.collection('favorites').add({
                website: form['website'].value,
                url: form['url'].value
            });    
        } else {
            let theCurrentUser = auth.currentUser;
                db.collection('users/'+ theCurrentUser.uid +'/bookmarks').add({
                website: form['website'].value,
                url: form['url'].value
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err.message);
            })
        }
        form.website.value = '';
        form.url.value = '';
    })
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This does exactly what I needed it to do.